# Why is the following matrix multiplication correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
Q_{1} & Q_{2}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\Lambda_{1} & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
Q_{1}^{T} \\
Q_{2}^{T}
\end{array}\right]=Q_{1} \Lambda_{1} Q_{1}^{T}
$$

Shouldn't the result be $\Lambda _{1}$ ?

Comment: i think that the first is true. Did you multiply it from left to right correctly

Comment: I restated my solution what I think it should be

Comment: Why is it urgent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its correct, since
$[Q_1,Q_2]\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\Lambda_1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} = [Q_1\Lambda_1, 0].$